# Can I use Twisted as STUN/TURN (ICE) Server?

Tags: twisted, webrtc, stun, rfc5766turnserver

I want to implement a WebRTC peer connection. I do not know how to setup an ICE server or what tool should I use. Can anyone advice me on this. Thank you very much.

Comment: you could but why would you want to? Here is an [EC2 image](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/source/browse/amazonlinuxami/turnserver-3.1.2.1-amazon-aws-ec2-x86_64.txt?spec=svn1019&r=1019) of the rfc5766 open Turn server. Works well and is already written.

Comment: I want to process the stream for object detection using OpenCV.

Comment: In the turn server? The server does not decode the streams. That processing could be done peer side and nothing to do with the server

Comment: If that's the case, what should I use to process the stream for object detection?

Comment: That is different question but you can still use opencv it will just have to be done on one of the peer sides

Comment: I have implemented the procedures but the streaming is not real-time. Here is the source https://github.com/dakilasoft/twistedcv and I also include the live demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you don't need to write your own STUN/TURN server

There are lots of ready solutions, especially this one is really good https://github.com/coturn/coturn/.

TURN is an extension of STUN, so TURN server supports all STUN operations as well

What you need is to install turn server on some server and put your WebRTC application to it

Comment: is there any turn client lib, i dont want full webrtc implementation. but just want to use turn protocol for communication between arduino client (which can communicate over tcp with turn server) and a linux host pc

Comment: @SudhirN I this case you do not need complex TURN. You just need to setup a simple TCP socket. Sort of https://www.industrialshields.com/blog/arduino-industrial-1/how-to-create-a-tcp-client-on-an-arduino-based-plc-55

Comment: Arduino needs to talk to a host PC which is behind NAT. Arduino and Host PC can not directly talk to each other, so I need a relay server in between which will pipe the traffic from arduino to host pc and vice versa, ofcourse i can implement that intermediate server myself using tcp, but i believe, this is what turn protocol does so i need a client library for turn

Comment: @SudhirN I feel using TURN w/o WebRTC would be an overkill nowadays and a bit overcomplicated, the communication protocol with TURN is pretty complex.  Implementing an intermediate server would be way easier at my opinion